# How to calculate the actual font size of an auto-font-sized PDF field?

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfsharp

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the actual font size that's used for a PDF acro field whenever its font size is set to 0 (auto). For example, "/ZaDb 0 Tf".

At present, I am using the ActivePDF toolkit to parse PDFs but am looking to move away from this toolkit to either iTextSharp LGPL 4.1.6 or PdfSharp. The last remaining piece of functionality that I need to port is the computed font size for an auto-sized field. ActivePDF conveniently populates the FieldInfo.FontSize property with the computed size for auto-sized fields, but I have so far been unsuccessful at figuring out how, exactly, the ActivePDF toolkit is performing its calculations for these types of fields.

According to the PDF spec, "A zero value for size means that the font shall be auto-sized: its size
shall be computed as a function of the height of the annotation rectangle." It's the latter part of this statement that I've been trying to figure out over the course of several days now. I have tried using the size of the annotation's rectangle as stated in the spec, using the boundary box that's associated with the field's appearance state, and just about everything else in between that I have been able to think of. Sometimes I get the same results as ActivePDF and other times I do not.

Any guidance on this would be extremely appreciated! I'm trying to get this to work for all interactive field types (button, text, choice, signature).

Comment: As you found out yourself, the specification is not particularly clear here. Thus, there is no single *correct* way to calculate the size. Many libraries try to emulate the calculations in Adobe Reader, and to do so quite some trial and error is required.

Comment: @mkl - ah! Very interesting! This has been driving me absolutely mad and I could have sworn that I was missing something in the specs. Makes a whole lot more sense now given that's the case! Thank you very much for taking the time to reply!! You just saved me countless hours of further struggle!

Answer (score 0):

Per @mkl's reply, there isn't a single *correct* answer to this question. The font size can only be approximated.

For others encountering this issue, I would recommend looking at the iTextSharp LGPL 4.1.6 codebase for such logic (specifically, the *GetAppearance* methods that can be found on the *BaseField* classes).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if zapfdingbats is the best example (since it is used for check mark of checkboxes).

We implemented our own PDF editor and for textfields we used something like: Take the dimensions of a formfield substract some padding (e.g. 2-5pixel), then use the font specified in the formfield and increase the height until it "hits" the boundary of the formfield coordinates (-padding). This value we are rounding "down" to the next full number. And then we are using this font size to display the text. (Note: this was the simplified version...)